# How do I build and validate a plain JavaScript-based code base?

Tags: javascript

My front end is an Angular 1.x project with tons of files. I basically need to validate it and find any errors that are there in any of the files. Specifically, errors that can break the page. In compiled/static type languages like Java, this is very easy, as the compiler will tell you exactly what's wrong. However, since JS is interpreted/dynamically typed, I can't figure out a way to "build" these files and find errors like I would for compiled languages. Going to every single page in the browser after I make any change is neither practical nor scalable.

I am also not using TypeScript or ES6 and it's not possible at the moment to migrate to any of them. Tools like ESLint and JSHint have also not been very successful, since they only bring out minor errors within that file. However, a lot of major code is spread over several files. Although my code is already all ES5, I thought about concatenating all JS files together in one file and running babel on it. But have it been sure how to manage dependencies during the concatenation (such as in what order to concatenate files).

This cant be the only project that uses vanilla JS and needs to be validated for errors. Anyone has any ideas on how I should go about accomplishing the task?

Comment: Do you have (AMD/CommonJS/UMD) modules in your project?

Comment: I don't. It's all plain JavaScript where JS files are all put in script tags in correct order to maintain dependency requirements. Basically the old way of having JavaScript in a web project.

Comment: I am sorry for you. I guess this is really hard to maintain... Do you know if the (revealing) module pattern is implemented in each file? If all your code is encapsulated in IIFEs, it would be easier for you to integrate a module loader/bundler like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/), [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). If not, I do not even imagine the mess in the global scope... Moreover, you may consider [Flow](https://flow.org/en/docs/getting-started/) to introduce type checking. It will require fewer modifications than TypeScript in your codebase.

Comment: Use [ESLint](http://eslint.org/), it has a plugin for Angular also.

Comment: @Badacadabra if I could make a change, it'd be to transition to Typescript and better manage dependencies. Right now there's so much stuff getting loaded that over time, the navigation and pages get slower, probably because the global scope is polluted. I guess some type of makeshift arrangement is the only way here

Comment: @DemCodeLines Your app is slow because your have a large amount of script tags in your HTML. The problem is that each script is considered as a resource to load and corresponds to an independent HTTP request. So if you can bundle or concatenate your scripts into a single file, do it. The server will love you if you request only one resource instead of 20. You should also consider using UglifyJS to minify the result. The file would be much lighter. :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend writing tests using [jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) and [karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html). I've found the two of these integrate really well with Angular and test driven development is highly regarded as one of the best development styles.

With all of this being said, I understand that's not what you're looking for directly because you want more of a "compiler" like solution. The closest thing that you can get to this in JS in my opinion is a linter and when combined with tests, this solution is rather good at finding errors in JS code.